# Connection Refused Error 61: Scrapy+splash Docker

Tags: javascript, docker, web-scraping, scrapy-splash

I've run into some problems scraping javascript sites. I'm using scrapy-splash with docker to render the js to html to scrape.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
class MySpider (scrapy.Spider):
       name = 'spd'
       start_urls = ['http://example.com']

       def start_requests (self):
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait':0.5},)
       def parse (self, response):
            for href in response.xpath('xpath'):
                   yield {'info': href.xpath('xpath')}
```

Here is what my terminal outputs:

```
  2017-05-30 13:20:51 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
  2017-05-30 13:20:51 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
  2017-05-30 13:20:51 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
  2017-05-30 13:20:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://example.com via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.
  2017-05-30 13:20:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://example.com via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.
  2017-05-30 13:20:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://example.com via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.
  2017-05-30 13:20:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://example.com via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html>: Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.
  2017-05-30 13:20:51 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: What problems?  You need to provide more info.  What are you expecting.  Are there specific errors?  What code are you using / started with.

Comment: Are you scrapping example.com or it is just an example?

Comment: example.com is just a placeholder for actual websites

Answer (score 0):

The following log messages indicate that the Splash docker container is either not running or isn't listening on the expected port.

```
DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://example.com via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.
DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://example.com via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.
DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://example.com via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.
```

To see the status of your Docker containers, including ones that have exited, try running:

```
sudo docker ps -a | grep scrapinghub/splash
```